# Hashtable hash-function implementation in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, random, hash, hashtable

I have array of random numbers from 100-1001 , which i transfer to hash table. 
Hash function is mod from n ( which is size of array ). 
The problem is, when im trying to check what is inside hashtable, it shows me different indexes from i have calculated on paper, so im confused if it works correct or not. 
Also as i was told, size of hash table must be at least 5% bigger than size of array, but i cannot find how to set hashtable size. Where do i have a mistake?
Ill have to search value by address using same hash-function after that.

```
    static void Main()
    {

        int n;

        Console.WriteLine("Please enter array size");
        n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        Random rnd = new Random();
        int[] a = new int[n + 4];

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            Console.Write("{0,4}", a[i] = rnd.Next(100, 1001));    
        // I have deleted code in the middle as there is certain type of search in array which works fine

        // Now putting values to hash table       

        Hashtable Hashtable = new Hashtable();
        int hashcode = n + ((n / 100) * 5);
        int value; 
        int key;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            value = a[i];
            key = value % hashcode;

            if (Hashtable[key] == null)
                Hashtable.Add(key, value);
            else
            {
                while (Hashtable[key] != null)
                {
                    if (key == (hashcode - 1))
                        key = 0;
                    else
                        key++;
                }
                Hashtable.Add(key, value);
            }
        }

              Console.WriteLine();
    }
```

Comment: On a different note, what is your problem here? What value are you expecting and what are you getting? We can't really do anything with "This code is somehow wrong, help me" questions.

Comment: I see , but it doesn't affect result anyway. I wrote this way to sea more clear that i want for 5% more addresses.

Comment: I was searching for how to use hash-table , but all examples i found on web are without hash-functions implemented, only static ones which are using built in functionality.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Are you trying to use a HashTable while manually specifying the hashes? Why not just use a Dictionary in that case?

Comment: For example: Array of values 839, 263, 438, 572, 501 are created by random where n=5. When values are transfered to hashtable , i check addreses, but they don't match with mods of these values as i did on paper.

Comment: Maybe this can be interesting for you: https://github.com/darrenkopp/murmurhash-net

Comment: I have to specify hash key manually using some function. The easiest function as i know is mod.

Comment: But *why* do you have to specify the hash key manually?

Comment: Coz im studying , and this is one of the requirements. And also all examples i found are in c++ which i don't understand so far. I dont want just to copy/paste code, i want to understand how that works.

Comment: Like I said before, please tell us what values you are getting from your program vs what you are expecting to get. What do the "addresses" of the hash table say, and what does your paper math say?

Comment: At this point, all I can say is that I copied your code into Visual Studio and it ran without a hitch. I can't say it ran as expected because you haven't told me what you are expecting.

Comment: I'd also like to ask what it is exactly you are studying. Every resource I can find says that from. NET 2.0 on, `Hashtable` has been rendered effectively obsolete by `Dictionary`. Are you studying the `Hashtable` class specifically or just hash tables in general?

Comment: I have just changed key = value % hashcode; to key = value % n; and now it works fine... i double checked with n=5 and n=11. Works good. I study algorithms and data structures, and this work is about hash-tables only. We have a book which describes idea in words. In the book it says that i have to create hash-table, which is 5% bigger then array. Im not sure, maybe in csharp hash-table is dynamic... But as i changed code now, where do i specify those 5%?

Comment: The `Hashtable` object in C# dynamically resizes when the number of available buckets is filled (specifically to the smallest prime number larger than `size * 2`), and the only time you can manually resize is when the table is first instantiated with the `new Hashtable(int capacity)` constructor. If you're doing this for research on hash tables in general, you should be looking into how to implement hash tables from scratch using arrays, not using existing collections. (Especially ones that no one would recommend for actual use.)

Comment: @Abion47 `(n/100)*5` is not the same as `n/20` if `n` is an int. The first will only go up to 5 when `n` reaches `100`, until then it will stay at `0`, whereas the latter will go to `1` when `n` reaches `20`, `2` at `40` and so on. In other words, for `n = 0, 20, 40, 60, 80, 100` the first expression will give you `0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5`, whereas the second will give you `0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5`.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a bit on confusion on how a hashtable works in .NET. A hashtable is an *associative list*. That means you can retrieve values by their keys, which is useful when an array or a list doesn't work, because you don't access values by their index (e.g. in a caching scenario). In order to quickly access the stored key/value pair, the hashtable *internally* calculates the hash code of the key to beable to store the data in buckets.

What you are doing is to calculate a "hash code" *externally* and then use it as a key to a hashtable. What the hashtable will do is to calculatate the hash code *of that key* to store the key/value pair. I'm pretty sure that's not what you want to do.

I would normally advise you to use a `Dictionary<int, int>`, but your case is different. Your key derives directly from the value you want to store, so your case is not a case for an assiciative list. I don't know exactly what you want to achieve, but your case looks most suited for a `HashSet` (that is a set that uses hash codes for storage of the values). You can override the `GetHashCode` method of your keys to change your hashing method, even though there is no necessity for that. In your case it will even degrade the efectiveness of the hash set, since your hash method is not only *very poor*, because it ranges for far less than the range of `Int32`, it will also cause a lot of collisions your hash set will have to work around.

Since you can not change the `GetHashCode`method of `int`, you have to create a wraper for that:

```
private struct HashCodeWrapper {
    private readonly int value;
    private readonly int n;

    public int Value {
        get {
            return value;
        }
    }

    public HashCodeWrapper(int value, int n) {
        this.value = value;
        this.n = n;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode() {
        return value % (n + ((n / 100) * 5));
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj) {
        return (obj is HashCodeWrapper) && ((HashCodeWrapper)obj).value.Equals(value);
    }
}
```

You can then create a `HashSet<HashCodeWrapper>` and add your wrappers to the set. If that doesn't work for you you have to implement your own version of a "hashtable".

But for all practical purposes, just use a `HashSet<int>` and save yourself a lot of work.